# Error in if (randomNumber <= p) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

I get a problem when I run this program in R.
anybody help me to solving this problem..?

```
par_1<-cbind(c(5.038159),c(3.899621))
par_2<-cbind(c(2.435457),c(13.89517))
tau<-365

  cdf2 <- function(x, help) {
    pgamma(x, shape=par_1[1], scale=par_1[2]) *
      pgamma(x, shape=par_2[1], scale=par_2[2])-help
  }

nextEventTime <- function(censoring) {
    randomNumber <- runif(n=1, min=0, max=1)
    pnew <- randomNumber * (1 - cdf2(censoring, 0)) + cdf2(censoring, 0)
    uniroot(f=cdf2, interval=c(0, 1000*tau), help=pnew)$root
  }
 hazardRate1 <- function(t) {
    dgamma(t, shape=par_1[1], scale=par_1[2]) /
      (1 - pgamma(t, shape=par_1[1], scale=par_1[2]))
  }
  hazardRate2 <- function(t) {
    dgamma(t, shape=par_2[1], scale=par_2[2]) /
      (1 - pgamma(t,shape=par_2[1], scale=par_2[2]))
  }
  nextEventType <- function(t) {
    p <- hazardRate1(t)/(hazardRate1(t)+hazardRate2(t))
    randomNumber <- runif(n=1, min=0, max=1)
    if (randomNumber <= p) {1} else {2}
    }


baris<-c(1:20000)
nexteventtime<-rep(0,time=20000)
nexteventype<-rep(0,time=20000)
dfnexteventime<-data.frame(baris,nexteventtime,nexteventype)
for(i in 1:nrow(dfnexteventime)){
dfnexteventime$nexteventtime[i]<-nextEventTime(dfnexteventime$nexteventtime[i])
dfnexteventime$nexteventype[i]<-nextEventType(dfnexteventime$nexteventtime[i])
}
View(dfnexteventime)
```

When I run this program, this program will error & produce output like this

```
Error in if (randomNumber <= p) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I think this problem because t value in  `nextEventType(t)` function can't zero (t!=0).
But `nextEventTime(dfnexteventime$nexteventtime[i])` never produce zero value, when I run this part for 10 times,

```
baris<-c(1:20000)
nexteventtime<-rep(0,time=20000)
nexteventype<-rep(0,time=20000)
dfnexteventime<-data.frame(baris,nexteventtime,nexteventype)
for(i in 1:nrow(dfnexteventime)){
dfnexteventime$nexteventtime[i]<-nextEventTime(dfnexteventime$nexteventtime[i])
}
```

without nextEventType function. This part never produce 0 value.
So, I confuse, what is a problem?.

I want result `nextEventType(t)` produce not zero value.
because if using zero value will be `Error in if(ramdonNumber <= p) { :...`

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal but reproducible example ie provide only details necessary and sufficient to reproduce the problem. The question as is is currently a bit broad since it requires one to go through the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't calling `nextEventType(t)` on zero, since this will never happen. However, the same error occurs whenever `nextEventType(t)` is called on a value of `t` greater than 195. At this point, the term `pgamma(t, shape=par_1[1], scale=par_1[2])` is so close to one that R evaluates `1 - pgamma(t, shape=par_1[1], scale=par_1[2])` to zero, so `hazardRate1(t)` returns `Inf`. Since `nextEventType(t)` is trying to assign `p` to `Inf/Inf`, `p` is never defined.

```
> p <- hazardRate1(196)/(hazardRate1(196) + hazardRate2(196))
> p
[1] NaN
```

This will only happen in very extreme cases, when you happen to draw > 195 in `nextEventTime(t)`, which only occurs around once in 30,000 random draws. That's why you don't see it when you run it 10 times, but often you do when you run it 20,000 times.

```r
random_draws <- numeric()
for(i in 1:1000000) random_draws[i] <- nextEventTime(0)
length(which(random_draws > 195))
# > [1] 28
```